# Force an R function call to be pure

Tags: r, purely-functional

### The problem

Is there a way to force a function call in R to be pure? Use case: [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/615#issuecomment-447585359). I want to protect the calling environment and its ancestors from modifications by the user's functions.

### Test case

```
before <- ls()
f <- function() {
  x <<- 1
  data("mtcars")
  return("abc")
}
output <- pure_function_call(f())
after <- setdiff(ls(), c("before", "f", "output"))
print(before)
print(after)
print(output)
```

### Requirements

- `before` and `after` must agree.
- Strings `"x"` and `"mtcars"` must be absent from both `before` and `after`.
- `output` must equal `"abc"`.
- `pure_function_call()` must call `f()` in the same R session that invokes the test case. E.g. `callr::r()` is not allowed.

### Failed past attempts

- `local(f())`
- `(function(){f()})()`

Comment: I don't see how this can be done. Functions in R use lexical scoping. So if you define `f` in the global scope, then when ever you call `f()` the `x<<-1` call will put the variable in the global scope. You'd have to change the environment for all defined functions which means basically creating all new functions.

Comment: @MrFlick It's maybe not exactly what the OP wants, but could you define `f` in a custom environment and then lock that environment? But you're right, I don't think you can lock the global environment.

Comment: @joran Right, you'd have to change how `f()` is defined is some way while still copying over any variables that it might use. Otherwise even if you `eval()` in a different environment, `f` still has a reference to the original global environment. It would be much easier to do this in a new, isolated session.

Comment: I forgot about environment locking. For the purposes of `drake`, it may be enough to just call `lockEnvironment()` at the right times. But then (1) how do I *unlock* the environment, and (2) how fast are these locking (and hopefully unlocking) operations?

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I came up with a course of action for `drake` that I think will work: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/619.